# How to cover these lines in test class for response

Tags: apex, unit-test, rest-api

How to cover these lines in test class for response

[image]

Comment: Please see the related Q&A. In essence, you need to write a HttpCalloutMock implementation, use Test.setMock to enable that mock for the callout, and return the desired return value from that interface. Once you do this, you will cover the rest of the code.

Comment: thank you so much for you help 
i did create a mock class 
``` 
@isTest
global class MockHttpResponseGenerator implements HttpCalloutMock {
    global HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {
       
        System.assertEquals('https://example.com/example/test', req.getEndpoint());
        System.assertEquals('GET', req.getMethod());
        
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.setBody('{"example":"test"}');
        res.setStatusCode(200);
        return res;
    }
}
```